# Assigning TA hours: Professional software implementing Student-project allocation with preferences algorithms

Tags: software

> **Q**: Do you have any suggestions on professional software that implements project allocation with preferences algorithms (short SAP-P)? Do you know any schools where they use professional software to allocate hours to TAs?

Our particular problem is assigning courses to 250 teaching assistants based on their preferences on courses and hours range (eg. 100-150 hours for semester).

**Operating system:** any will do.

**Budget:** price can be quite flexible because as of now multiple people are hired to do this task. Ideally we want to hear what software brands are generally available that solve this problem and then think about price.

**Features:** The input would be a a)list of prioritized courses (eg. size 10) from 250 students (TAs) and b)the preferred work hours for the year.

The only important constraints are how many TAs and hours are needed for each course. So if a course requires more students, then some of the TAs' preferences will be ignored.

So this software will at least get the job done. But ideally there are other things it can do:

a)It can use the TAs' course history, to correct for giving them courses in the past that were not high in their list.

b)It can use the TAs' teaching score from student reviews, to match them with the courses they actually did well.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I wonder if this might be appropriate (and also get more responses) on the Academia site than Math Educators?

Comment: This seems like a rather common scheduling problem, one that you might face in every company where jobs need to be assigned. Thus, I would suggest not to look solely for an academic software, but browse the offers of scheduling programs flying around and find the one that can be adjusted to your needs. I'm sure there is also a SE-page that might help you here, but unfortunately I don't know which one.

Comment: Sure, we found plenty, but I would much rather have someone suggest software that some universities already use and does a good job. It will be nice to have some testimonies.

Comment: I asked a software question on academia, and it was moved to [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  It didn't really get answered there, but it might help for you.